# How to find rewrite rule applying on Wordpress website login URL?

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

I wonder which directory or folder "wordpress login url rename" rule is saved. I changed my website login url using "WPS Hide login" and "AIOS" plugins, both worked properly, but i can't find where their changes are applied. I checked all folders which were created by these plugins and also .htaccess file, but this rule doesn't exist in these paths. I would appreciate that if you could guide me finding the code which is changing my login page.

as mentioned in previous description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value stored in the `wp_options` table - it's not saved to a file. I don't recall the key they use for it, but I know it's in there. They use a WP filter to redirect the login url.